# clang_complete is breaking my vim key binding

Tags: vim

I'm trying to map tab in visual mode so I can indent a block of code with it. I can use < and > but I want tab to do it because that is standard for most text editors and IDEs. This is how I am mapping tab to indent:

```
vnoremap <Tab> >gv
vnoremap <S-Tab> <gv
```

This works fine until I load the clang_complete plugin and it even works with it when I am not in a C++ file. I opened up the plugin and see no mappings to do this. I saw a mapping that used tab in the snippets/clang_complete.py file but when I comment it out nothing changes. Why is this happening and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
:verbose vmap <Tab>
```

will tell you which visual mode mapping is defined (in a C++ buffer), and from where. You'll recognize a buffer-local mapping by the `@` prefix. With that, you can probably remove or `:vunmap` the mapping.